# Specifying a text delimiter in FileHelpers record class definition

Tags: c#, text, struct, filehelpers

I am a new user for FileHelpers, trying to parse a comma delimited text file.  The parser in Excel has the concept of BOTH a field delimiter (such as a comma) AND a text delimiter (such as double quotes) for fields that contain funky stuff you want to pass through to the receiving field in the structure.  The package generating the file may or may not include the text delimiter depending on the content of the data in the field.

I have searched the documentation and this site, but have not found whether this is possible, although it seems to be a common function.

Is there a way to specify a text delimiter to the DelimitedFileEngine, the same way that you can define  [DelimitedRecord(",")] to the class definition of the record you are parsing?

Comment: OK, my apologies. After continuing to dig, I've found the attribute [FieldQuoted()] to be applied at the field level.  Upon rebuilding and testing, found another issue.  I have an optional field marked with [FieldOptional], and get a runtime exception suggesting I mark the field as [FieldOptional].  My apologies as I work through getting the syntax correct for my first usage.  I have big plans for Filehelper.

Comment: That would be [a new question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). And we need to [see some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help.